# What Google apps script APIs require OAuth access token?

Tags: google-apps-script, oauth-2.0, google-api

Google apps script provides the [**ScriptApp.getOAuthToken()**](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/script/script-app#getOAuthToken()) API to get the OAuth 2.0 access token for the effective user. The API document says that the token can be used for Google APIs that requires OAuth like Google Picker.

However, apart from Google Picker (e.g. in this [example](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/dialogs#file-open_dialogs)), I haven't found any other APIs that require this OAuth token. Anyone can help me find such APIs? Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Almost all Google APIs can be accessed with the OAuthToken provided you have [authorized](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/concepts/scopes#setting_explicit_scopes) such [scopes](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/googlescopes). You can find a list of APIs [here](https://console.cloud.google.com/apis/library)

Comment: Thanks for the reply! My question is about Google apps script APIs, but your link basically points to all Google APIs.

Comment: @Thanh All(most) Google APIs are accessible from Google apps script.

Answer (score 0):

To navigate to the API library from the code editor, do the following:

- Open the Apps Script code editor
- Click the Resources menu and the "Cloud platform project" menu item
- Click the blue link
- Open the Nav menu
- Choose "APIs & Services" and Library

[image: API Library]

Comment: Thanks for the reply! But you're basically pointing me to all Google APIs.

Comment: Apps Script can make HTTPS Requests using `UrlFetchApp.fetch(url)`, which means that any API that has a REST API, can be called from Apps Script.  How the API receives the token depends on that particular API.